# What's the best way to refresh TensorBoard after new events/logs were added?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

What is the best way to quickly see the updated graph in the most recent event file in an open TensorBoard session? Re-running my Python app results in a new log file being created with potentially new events/graph. However, TensorBoard does not seem to notice those differences, unless restarted.

Comment: does reloading the webpage help?

Comment: Only occasionally. And often I need to re-run my code several times (meaning create several identical new logs) before refreshing will do anything. Then after multiple refreshes sometimes it will pick up the changes, but frequently it will not and requires killing the server. Also, after a refresh, since the URL does not indicate the open tab, it will switch the current tab summaries. This is too many steps for it to be currently usable.

Comment: Can you clarify - when you say "updated graph" you mean the graph visualizations? Or the charts in the event dashboard?

Comment: I mean graph visualizations.

Answer (score 15):

It turns out that TensorBoard backend refreshes the logs every minute. This has been reported as a [TensorFlow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2050).

The reload interval can be configured using the `--reload_interval` flag of the TensorBoard process, but this option is currently only available in master and as of version 0.8 has not been released.

Comment: What about summaries that have been deleted? Somehow a deleted set of experiment summaries is still showing up even after tensorboard has been restarted and loaded in different browsers (to avoid caching in the browser).

Comment: Does tensorboard backend reload when the frontend page refreshes?

Comment: But what to actually type in? This answer is not self contained, and only leads to [this semi-joke](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2050#issuecomment-282142808)

Answer (score 3):

I advise to always start tensorboard with `--reload_multifile True` to force reloading all event files.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is different. Each time I refresh `0.0.0.0:6006`, it seems the new graph keep appending to the old one, which is quite annoying.

After trying kill process and delete old log several times, I realized the issue comes from `writer.add_graph(sess.graph)`,  because I didn't **reset the graph** in jupyter notebook.  After resetting, the tensorboard could show the newest gragh.

Comment: Consider putting this answer as a comment.