# Multiple Event files on Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using Tensorboard to show the training results of the code using Tensorflow (0.7). The previous Tensorflow version had [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233767/event-files-in-google-tensorflow) for multiple event files: when I run my local server using `$ tensorboard --logdir=./tmp/`, it shows up error if there are more than 1 event files. It seems that the latest version (0.7) does not show up the same error for multiple event files, but it still shows the overlapped curves for multiple event files on Tensorboard. I wonder how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Training my own networks, I am writing summaries in different subfolders like `/tmp/project/train`  and `/tmp/project/eval`. If you start TensorBoard using

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/project/
```

you will still receive multiple graphs from each event file in the subfolders at once, as you mentioned. To see seperate graphs you can start TensorBoard from the desired subfolder:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/project/train/
```

Answer (score 0):

I second ArnoXf's answer. You should use different subfolders for each experiment and assuming the logging root is `/tmp` start tensorboard using:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/
```

If you want to display just a single graph you can either pass that directory to your tensorboard call as described in ArnoXf's answer.
However, with the above call you can also select your graph directly in tensorboard, i.e., deactivate all others. The same way you can also compare individual runs as shown in the following screenshot. In my opinion, this is usually the preferred option, as it gives you more flexibility.

[image: tensorboard screenshot with individual runs checkboxes ready to toggle displayed on the left]

A detailed example can be found [here](http://hoolihan.net/blog-tim/2018/07/13/using-tensorboard-with-multiple-model-runs/).